# Cordova Android javascript to check multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

This function executes when a button is tapped. All the code works except for the first 'if' statement when I am trying to check if both 'dland' and 'advent' are checked off. See the bold code below. That if statement should execute function 'randomItinerary1' if both the 'dland' and 'advent' checkboxes are marked. The problem must lie with checking the booleans of two checkboxes in one if statement and I need a workaround. Thank you all in advance for your time and consideration.

```
$("#q1").on("tap", function(){

    //var cv2 = $('#advent:checked').val();
    navigation(page2, page4);

    **if ((document.getElementById('dland').checked) && (document.getElementById('advent').checked))** {
        randomItinerary1();
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('dland').checked) {
        randomItinerary2();
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('advent').checked) {
        randomItinerary3();
    }
    else {
        alert("You didn't select and parks");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: could u do if(document.getElementById('dland').checked == true && document.getElementById('advent').checked == true)

Comment: Unfortunately this did now work either. I tried all variations of this suggestion. if((document.getElementById('dland').checked == true) && (document.getElementById('advent').checked == true)) also tried if(((document.getElementById('dland').checked) && (document.getElementById('advent').checked ))) == true)

Comment: hmm tried to recreate your problem here but it worked https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhuLum/

Comment: can u show the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, it works for all condition

https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhuLum/

```
   $("#q1").on("click", function(){
  if ((document.getElementById('dland').checked) &&             (document.getElementById('advent').checked)) {
    alert("both checked")
  }
   if (document.getElementById('dland').checked) {
   alert("dland checked")
  }
   if (document.getElementById('advent').checked) {
    alert("advent checked")
  }

   else {
        alert("You didn't select and parks");
    }
});
```